# How to return a list of the selected points in Bokeh?

Tags: selection, bokeh

I want to be able to return a list of the selected points from any selection tool (box selection tool, tap tool, etc.) from a Bokeh plot. How do I do that? Here's an example of how I'd create the plot. Thanks!

```
from bokeh.io import vform
from bokeh.models import CustomJS
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import OpenURL, CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, Div, WheelZoomTool, TapTool, BoxSelectTool, BoxZoomTool, PanTool, ResetTool, SaveTool

output_notebook()

# Create Column Data Source that will be used by the plot
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2,3]))

# Create figure
p = figure(plot_height=600, plot_width=700, title='', tools = [TapTool(), BoxSelectTool()])

p.circle(x='x', y='y', source=source, size=8, fill_alpha=0.33, line_color=None)

# Display data
show(p, notebook_handle=True);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Jupyter notebook that demonstrates communication between Javascript and Python kernel.

https://github.com/ruoyu0088/interactive_graph/blob/master/07-embed%20bokeh%20figure%20in%20ipywidget.ipynb

I am sorry the text is in Chinese, but you can just run the code (download the notebook and the bokehelp.py) and you will get following widget.

Right side is a scatter plot selected by lasso tool, left side is the index of selected points.

[image]

Comment: Which version of bokeh should this work with? It appears to be comprehensively broken with v1.0.4.